# How to get all values of checked checkboxes in JavaScript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a set of checkboxes in an html form similar to this

```
<form action = "/submit" method = "POST">  
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val1" name="value[]" value="Apple">
    <label for="val1"> Apple </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val2" name="value[]" value="Banana">
    <label for="val2"> Banana </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val3" name="value[]" value="Pear">
    <label for="val3"> Pear </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val4" name="value[]" value="Grinadella">
    <label for="val4"> Grinadella </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

The form content is stored in a database. The storage works, however I can only get the value of the first checkbox and store it in the database. What I want to do is that if the user selects the first three checkboxes, I want to store the value `Apple, Banana, Pear` in the database separated by commas.

How can I do this. I know that in PHP there is a function called `implode` that does this, but how can I extend the form so that I get all values of checked checkboxes in `JS/Node.js`
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can first select all the *checked* check boxes using `querySelectorAll(':checked')`. Then you can [**`map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) them to find the value. Finally [**`join()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them to get the string.

**Demo:**

```js
function getAllChecked(){
 var checked = document.querySelectorAll(':checked');
 var res = Array.from(checked).map(c => c.value).join(', ');
 console.log(res);
 return false; // prevent the form submission
}
```

```html
<form action = "/submit" method = "POST">
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val1" name="value[]" value="Apple">
    <label for="val1"> Apple </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val2" name="value[]" value="Banana">
    <label for="val2"> Banana </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val3" name="value[]" value="Pear">
    <label for="val3"> Pear </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val4" name="value[]" value="Grinadella">
    <label for="val4"> Grinadella </label>
  </div>
  <button onclick="return getAllChecked()">Show Checked</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the value of the check boxes

```
var checkBox = req.body.checkBox

if(checkBox ===true)
console.log('It is true')
```

I hope you get my point !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) & [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods:

```js
var checkedBoxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.styled:checked')]
var values = checkedBoxes.map(c => c.value).join(', ')
console.log(values)
```

```html
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
  <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val1" name="value[]" value="Apple" checked>
  <label for="val1"> Apple </label>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
  <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val2" name="value[]" value="Banana" checked>
  <label for="val2"> Banana </label>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
  <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val3" name="value[]" value="Pear" checked>
  <label for="val3"> Pear </label>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
  <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val4" name="value[]" value="Grinadella">
  <label for="val4"> Grinadella </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each checkbox input a different name, then access in your post request from req.body.

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val1" name="value1" value="Apple" checked>
  <label for="val1"> Apple </label>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
  <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val2" name="value2" value="Banana" checked>
  <label for="val2"> Banana </label>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
  <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val3" name="value3" value="Pear" checked>
  <label for="val3"> Pear </label>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-danger checkbox-md">
  <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="val4" name="value4" value="Grinadella">
  <label for="val4"> Grinadella </label>
</div>
```

POST request:

```
const {
value1,
value2,
value3,
value4
       } = req.body;
```

Log values:

```
console.log(value1);
console.log(value2);
console.log(value3);
console.log(value4);
```